# Checking for duplicates on update with EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I'm currently making an app that has unique columns

```
public class Category
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Where Name is declared unique in my DBContext.OnModelCreating() method.

This is working as intended.

With insert I can check for duplicates with something like this:

```
if(_context.Category.Any(c => c.Name == category.Name))
{
     ViewData["Message"] = "A category with that name already exist";
     return View();
}
```

Now my problem is, when editing this entity, how do I check if the edited name exist in the case where it gets edited to match another existing row in the DB?

To explain this better, let's assume I have 2 entries in my table.

- A: ID = 1, Name =  "Pants"
- B: ID = 2, Name = "Shirts"

If I then try to rename As Name to be "Shirts" I get an duplicate error. How do I handle this usecase?

Comment: _context.Category.Any(c => c.Id != category.Id && c.Name == category.Name)

Comment: Thank you. Seems obvious now that I see it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the same thing when updating with an extra check to verify that the name to update is not the same as the existing name:

```
if(_context.Category.Any(c => c.Name == newNameAfterUpdate && c.Name != category.Name))
{
     ViewData["Message"] = "A category with that name already exist";
     return View();
}
```